# Jquery form post errors

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am new in Jquery.
I'm working on a form. Title and text (textarea)
When I fill out the fields and click send, the two alerts appear when I click OK two times to scroll the page up.
Now I fill in the fields and then it starts again from the beginning.

How can I ensure that after the two checks continues the page?

Jquery:

```
    $("#formPages").submit( function(event) {
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var text = $('#text').val();
        if(title == ''){
            $("#titleError").html("<p>Fill Title</p>");
            alert('title empty');
        }       
        if(text == ''){
            $("#textError").html("<p>Fill Text</p>");
            alert('text empty');
        }       
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        event.preventDefault();          
    });
```

Form:

```
<form class="form" id="formPages">
<div>
    <label class="title">Title</label>
    <div id="titleError"></div>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="">

</div>
<div>
    <label class="title">Text</label>
    <div id="textError"></div>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" rows="14" cols="50"></textarea><br />

</div>
<div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `event.preventDefault();` when outside of the **IF** statements. Your code should work like this:

```
$("#formPages").submit( function(event) {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var text = $('#text').val();
    if(title == ''){
        $("#titleError").html("<p>Fill Title</p>");
        alert('title empty');
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }       
    if(text == ''){
        $("#textError").html("<p>Fill Text</p>");
        alert('text empty');
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }       
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);         
});
```

Have not tested it but should work as expected, comment if any errors.
to check if the textarea or the title are empty will be better to use `if (text.length === 0)` and `if (title.length === 0)`

**EDIT**

Please check the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2n2S4/) for a working example, I have tested it with Chrome, FF, and IE(I know :D)

Comment: Almost! The textarea is now the problem. If i fill it i am getting the error. If i remove the text error handling it works.

Comment: Could you -please create a fiddle of your form without the PHP and with the JS cuz for some reason I cannot simulate the errors

Comment: @Bas DaGhostman is referring to the [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) site where you can create a live working example of your code. Just put your code into the appropriate blocks (HTML/Javascript/CSS) and click Save. Since you are using jQuery, you must also choose that (under Frameworks and Extensions). When you SAVE it will give you a URL which you can post here.

Comment: Please check my edit and try the jQuery code instead and tell me if it works

Comment: Still the textarea gives the problem. Chrome FF IE

Comment: Yes i have implement that into my script

Comment: Is it working with it? And if it is feel free to hit the `Accept Answer` sign next to my answer or ask if you need any assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `event.preventDefault()` statement keeps the form from being submitted. This statement should only be used if something in the form is invalid, and you don't want the form submitted. Otherwise, removing it will allow the form to submit to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend using Jquery validation plug in, especially if you have more than one form , it does exactly what you want, it validate forms.

Now for your problem, you always prevent the form from submitting because you always do  `event.preventDefault()`, you need to prevent the submit only if something is invalid in your form, try like this instead :

```
$("#formPages").submit( function(event) {
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var text = $('#text').val();
    var isValid = true;

    if(title == ''){
        $("#titleError").html("<p>Fill Title</p>");
        alert('title empty');
        isValid = false;
    }    

    if(text == ''){
        $("#textError").html("<p>Fill Text</p>");
        alert('text empty');
        isValid = false;
    }       

    if(!isValid){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    }
});
```

Comment: I try this, but here also the textarea problem.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what DaGhostman has already said about putting the event.preventDefault() statement underneath each `if` statement, your form tag does not specify what to do upon submission.

Forms have to be POSTed somewhere in order for the data to be processed. The name of the processing file, and the delivery method, must be specified in the `<form>` tag.

You have:

```
<form class="form" id="formPages">
```

You should have:

```
<form class="form" id="formPages" action="yourProcessorFile.php" method="POST">
```

Then, you must have a PHP file that will receive and process the form data. Notes:

- The form data is delivered as an associative array, called $_POST.
- The `name` attribute on each form element becomes the KEY (or variable name) in the $_POST array
- The value typed into the field becomes the value of that variable in the PHP file.

For example, the PHP processor file could look like this (using the same filename I used for the `action=` attribute above):

**yourProcessorFile.php**

```
<?php
    $t = $_POST['title'];
    $x = $_POST['text'];

    echo '<h1>Received From Form:</h1>;
    echo 'Title: ' .$t. '<br>';
    echo 'Text: ' .$x. '<br>';
```